# Convert Bytecode to Date

Tags: timestamp, bytecode

I have a Table with a column 'Date'. But the date is in Bytecode. Is there a way to convert it in a Timestamp?

b'\x9d2\x9a\\x00\x00\x00\x00\x12\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'

b'x6\x9a\\x00\x00\x00\x00\xa3\x02\x00\x00\xd07K\xb6'

b'^]\x9a\\x00\x00\x00\x00\xa3\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'

Comment: "Bytecode" does not seem like a correct term here. Can you indicate how these pieces of data were generated?

Comment: Looks like some 128 bit number. But how are *we* supposed to know, how this encodes a date?